# Rearrange the following equation into the form of $y=mx+c$ so the gradient can be used to determine the value of RC: $V=V_0(1-e^{-\frac{t}{RC}})$

Tags: logarithms

Rearrange the following equation into the form of $y=mx+c$ so the gradient can be used to determine the value of RC:
$$V=V_0(1-e^{-\frac{t}{RC}})$$

I've used logs to get it to $$\frac{RC(\ln V_0)}{RC (\ln V_0)-t}=\ln(V)$$

I'm not sure if this is actually possible but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$$e^{-\frac{t}{RC}}=1-\frac{V}{V_0}$$
$$\frac{1}{RC}t+\ln\left(1-\frac{V}{V_0}\right)=0$$
You can now do the Taylor expansion around $V=0$, so you get a line. Note that in this case you must use $V\ll V_0$.

Comment: But, the data that im graphing has V >$V_0$

Comment: Really? This looks like an equation from physics/electronics, the charging of the capacitor. As $t$ goes to $\infty$, $V$ goes to $V_0$. $V$ is always less that $V_0$ unless $t/(RC)$ is a complex number.

Comment: As t increases V gets larger than $V_0$, this is my issue in graphing it as a straight line

Comment: $V_0$ is a constant, not $V(0)$. The more accurate name should be $V_\infty$

Comment: why V(infinity) as $V_0$ is the starting value and then V increases above $V_0$

Comment: What is the value of $V$ if you plug in $t=\infty$ in your equation? What is the value of $V$ if you plug in $t=0$ in your equation?

Comment: when $t=0, V=0.01=V_0$. and as the value of t increases the v tends towards 6

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84124/discussion-between-andrei-and-h-linkhorn).